# how to remove physics shape in Xcode simulator

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

how to remove physics shape in Xcode simulator.when i run my test app in Xcode simulator i get following shapes combined, how to remove it.

[image]

Comment: And What you have tried? Is this a image?

Comment: Are you following a tutorial? Those shapes are probably meant as a demonstration, try to find the declarations and references and just delete them all. Though im unfamiliar with box2d so for all i know they could be something different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/606/how-to-use-box2d-for-just-collision-detection-with-cocos2d-iphone) is what you are looking for. 
All the best.! :)